# using (complex) c struct in c#

Tags: c#, c

I have some easy methods and a C `struct` which basically looks like this:

```
struct A
{
   B* b;
   C* c;
   int d;
}

void createA(A** a);
void freeA(A** a);
int doCrazyStuff(A* a);
```

In a way I do not care about the structs in the C# code. I only want to create a pointer of A and use this pointer in the C# code via the C methods.

Does anyone have a minimal example for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are using is an "opaque" pointer... or an handle. Your C# program doesn't know what `A*` is and isn't interested in knowing it.

You can directly use an `IntPtr` like this:

```
void createA(out IntPtr a);
void freeA(ref IntPtr a);
int doCrazyStuff(IntPtr a);
```

To be type-safe you could:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyA
{
    public IntPtr Ptr;
}

void createA(out MyA a);
void freeA(ref MyA a);
int doCrazyStuff(MyA a);
```

it wouldn't change anything, but if you have multiple opaque references, then you wouldn't be able to mix them (if you have two sets of methods, one that uses `A*` and another that uses `B*`, with the first "way" you could mix the `IntPtr`, while with the second one you couldn't)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I have two more questions.

1.) Using an object of A in C# works now like this?
MyA mya;
createA(&mya);
doCrazyStuff(mya);
freeA(&mya);

2.) Why do the parameter of createA() and freeA() differ?

Comment: @mueldgog No, you write `createA(out mya), doCrazyStuff(mya); freeA(ref mya)`. I've used different `out` and `ref` because the `createA` initializes `mya` without reading it, while `freeA` seems to read `mya` and then modify it (probably setting it to `NULL`). You could use `ref` everywhere, but then you would have to initialize `mya` with `MyA mya = new MyA()` before calling `createA`